# Run certbot manual with DNS challenge

Tags: certbot

I have installed certbot 0.40.0 and i want to generate manually a certificate running a DNS challenge.

```
certbot certonly -d DOMAIN --manual --prefered-challenge DNS
```

This used to work before but now i get the following message.

```
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --prefered-challenges dns
```

Is their a way to select the challenge you want to run?

Comment: Typo: `--preferred-challenges` (double `r` and a trailing `s`)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to check in the --help but that argument is not included.

Comment: Then you probably have a old certbot version. `man certbot` [displays it like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2gZ1.png).

Comment: I had the same issue and saw the correct spelling when I typed `certbot -h all` rather than `certbot -h`